# how to allow ads in chrome in my automation script?

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, automation, ads

I have a google login scenario ,

1. open website click login with google
2. google popup opens to add the email then pass then click login

Expected: I should log in to the website

Actual: I can not log in unless the open site setting and allow ads

[image]

so is there any way to add code to allow ads during running the script

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("profile.managed_default_content_settings.ads", 1); 
chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
```

use preference , see all supported pref at :

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/66.0.3359.158/components/content_settings/core/common/pref_names.cc

**Note:** preference is not supported for headless browser

As of Feb , 2021

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1925

Headless chrome doesn't support preferrences setting .