# Downloading data using Selenium by clicking button?

Tags: python, selenium

I am attempting to download data from the [CDC](https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/#testing_positivity7day) via Selenium. I am having some trouble however since I am new to Selenium. Here is what I have:

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import os

def enable_download_headless(browser,download_dir):
    browser.command_executor._commands["send_command"] = ("POST", '/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command')
    params = {'cmd':'Page.setDownloadBehavior', 'params': {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': download_dir}}
    browser.execute("send_command", params)

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--verbose')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--disable-software-rasterizer')

download_dir = "Downloads"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path="C:\Windows\System32\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
enable_download_headless(driver, download_dir)
driver.get("https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/#testing_positivity7day")

python_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='dwn-testing-img']")
print(python_button)
```

I found [this](https://cdc.112.2o7.net/b/ss/cdcgov/1/JS-2.20.0/s6481896200420?AQB=1&ndh=1&pf=1&t=18%2F1%2F2021%2019%3A1%3A26%204%20300&fid=40BE341F4F340E9B-00BF0A48D910B6B4&ce=UTF-8&g=https%3A%2F%2Fcovid.cdc.gov%2Fcovid-data-tracker%2F%23testing_positivity7day&cc=USD&ch=Coronavirus&c2=https%3A%2F%2Fcovid.cdc.gov%2Fcovid-data-tracker%2F%23testing_positivity7day&c31=https%3A%2F%2Fcovid.cdc.gov%2Fcovid-data-tracker%2F%23testing_positivity7day&c40=cdt-interaction%3A%20export%20%3E%20covid19_tests_performed_by_state.csv&c46=https%3A%2F%2Fcovid.cdc.gov%2Fcovid-data-tracker%2F%23testing_positivity7day&pe=lnk_o&pev2=CDC%20COVID%20Data%20Tracker&pid=CDC%20COVID%20Data%20Tracker%20-%20testing_positivity7day&pidt=1&oid=blob%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fcovid.cdc.gov%2F67666d2c-8d5d-4754-942d-ace012b66627&ot=A&s=456x850&c=24&j=1.6&v=N&k=Y&bw=456&bh=850&lrt=228&AQE=1) URL by doing the network inspector on Chrome's dev tools. No idea how to use it though, seeing it does not link to a CSV directly.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGhy8.png) is an image of the button I am trying to click. However, in the above code, I am trying to click the download image button since I know it is exposed/not hidden by the collapsible div. I have tried a few different things but no luck. I tried downloading the URL directly via Panda's.to_csv method but it did not work either.

Comment: headless browser doesn't support preferrence

Comment: Good to know. I will probably just remove the whole add_experimental_option and it would make the code less verbose. I am just having issues with the main functionality coding bloat aside.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66088712/6793637

Comment: Updated to remove, thanks for the tip

Comment: try this : https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/COVIDData/getAjaxData?id=US_MAP_TESTING

Comment: How did you do that? I was just getting Selenium working too, but your solution would be way more convenient

Comment: open console, in the network tab, refresh the page, check data requests...
Word of advice : recon before coding ;)

Comment: Duly noted, thank you! Now I just need to load it into a pandas dataframe, hopefully not too hard

Comment: Done, now I have live data. Thanks for the help!